# django channels message.reply_channel no attribute send

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I've been trying to get my head around the channels of Django and I can't get my message to be sent to my websocket.

Here is my `consumers.py`

```
import logging
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.utils import timezone
from channels import Group
from .models import *
import json

def send_free(message):
    try:
        pi = PInformation.objects.get(
            pk=message.content.get('pk'),
        )
    except Parkplatzinformationen.DoesNotExist:
        logging.error("PI not found!")
        return

    try:
        message.reply_channel.send({
        "text": 1,
    })
    except:
        logging.exception('Problem sending %s' % (pi.name))
```

My `routing.py`

```
from channels.routing import route

from RESTAPI.consumers import send_free

channel_routing = [
    route('send-free',send_free),
]
```

I'm getting the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`. It does however get the PInformation object so it does work a "bit". I'm calling it right after I'm saving the object.

Could you please give me some hints? [The Getting Started guide](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html) uses it like I try to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are calling `"send-free"` from your view like this...

```
Channel('send-free').send({'message': 'your message'})
```

Then `send_free` doesn't have the `message.reply_channel`...

In other word once the `WebSocket packet is sent to us by a client` then message takes the `reply_channel` attribute from it. That will use to reply message back to client... ( to frontend maybe )

So do you really want to send message...? then again send using consumers...

Comment: Yes you are correct I'm calling the send-free the way you described it. However I do not get what do you mean by repeating the process.

Comment: @dowu Repeat `Channel("cons").send(dict)` and also I edited the answer..

Comment: Okay so I call `Channel("otherchanel").send(dict)` instead of `message.reply_channel.send` again? Isn't "otherchannel" supposed to be linked to a function and so I'm stuck with the same problem?

Comment: What message your are trying to send back and why ? You are calling the consumer function from your view then you are expecting your consumer to send back the message back to view ?

Comment: I want to send a dict to the client after the object has been updated so I can display that information on a homepage (retrieving it with javascript). (thank you for your patience)

Comment: In your `send_free` consumer... broadcast your message using `Group("chat").send({"text": "msg"})` so this way you are sending message back to frontend